# Powershell runbook errors after update to OMS New Query Language

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation, azure-log-analytics

It turned out that after migration to New Query Language in OMS also WebhookData structure for alert has changed.

I was trying to change my powershell script (which is called at OMS alert via Automation Account runbook) and it works locally for the Input I've copied for some previous (updated) alerts but I cannot get it to work in Automation Account.

Can anyone tell why this don't work in Runbook but works locally?

Here is my runbook input: https://jsonblob.com/adf5e1c2-c948-11e7-af9e-2d30dd548850

I took it from here:
[image]

Script:

```
$WebhookData = '{"WebhookName":"OMS Alert Remediation b64051e5-b9c5-44db-b74f-51d7cf5a9df2","RequestBody":"{\"WorkspaceId\":\"8547d992-7979-46d0-912b-8fffeabe1c8b\",\"AlertRuleName\":\"SRVR slow response - TEST\",\"SearchQuery\":\"ApplicationInsights | where TelemetryType == \\\"Request\\\" and Computer startswith_cs \\\"SRVR\\\" and Computer != \\\"SRVR-DEVEL\\\" | summarize AggregatedValue = avg(RequestDuration) by bin_at(TimeGenerated, 4m, datetime(2017-11-12T10:32:00.0000000)), Computer | sort by TimeGenerated desc\",\"SearchResult\":{\"tables\":[{\"name\":\"PrimaryResult\",\"columns\":[{\"name\":\"TimeGenerated\",\"type\":\"datetime\"},{\"name\":\"Computer\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"AggregatedValue\",\"type\":\"real\"}],\"rows\":[[\"2017-11-12T10:28:00Z\",\"SRVR-06\",1535.2852333333333],[\"2017-11-12T10:24:00Z\",\"SRVR-06\",718.91287857142856]]}]},\"SearchIntervalStartTimeUtc\":\"2017-11-12T10:27:00Z\",\"SearchIntervalEndtimeUtc\":\"2017-11-12T10:32:00Z\",\"AlertThresholdOperator\":\"Greater Than\",\"AlertThresholdValue\":700,\"ResultCount\":2,\"SearchIntervalInSeconds\":300,\"LinkToSearchResults\":\"https://8547d992-7979-46d0-912b-8fffeabe1c8b.portal.mms.microsoft.com/#Workspace/search/index?_timeInterval.intervalEnd=2017-11-12T10%3a32%3a00.0000000Z&_timeInterval.intervalDuration=300&q=ApplicationInsights%20%20%7C%20where%20TelemetryType%20%3D%3D%20%5C%22Request%5C%22%20and%20Computer%20startswith_cs%20%5C%22SRVR%5C%22%20and%20Computer%20!%3D%20%5C%22SRVR-DEVEL%5C%22%20%20%7C%20summarize%20AggregatedValue%20%3D%20avg(RequestDuration)%20by%20bin_at(TimeGenerated%2C%204m%2C%20datetime(2017-11-12T10%3A32%3A00.0000000))%2C%20Computer%20%20%7C%20sort%20by%20TimeGenerated%20desc\",\"Description\":\"W runbook-u testujemy powershell workflow, zamiast powershel script \",\"Severity\":\"Critical\"}","RequestHeader":{"Connection":"Keep-Alive","Accept":"application/json","Host":"s2events.azure-automation.net","User-Agent":"OMS-Remediation","x-ms-request-id":"9be297e0-c196-45c0-ad23-3b513e165648"}}'

$Input = ConvertFrom-Json $WebhookData
$RequestBody = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $Input.RequestBody

$Computers = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList

foreach($row in $RequestBody.SearchResult.tables[0].rows)
{
    $Computers.Add($row[1]) > $null
}

foreach ($Computer in $Computers | Get-Unique)
{
    'Computer: ' + $Computer
    Invoke-Command -Credential $c -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {
        $date = Get-Date | Out-File -Append 'C:\tmp\test_log.txt' 
    }
}
```

And those are errors in Azure Portal: 
[image: Error in Azure Portal]

1.

```
ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: .
At line:9 char:10
+ $Input = ConvertFrom-Json $WebhookData
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand
```

2.

```
ConvertFrom-Json : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At line:10 char:46
+ $RequestBody = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $Input.RequestBody
+                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJs
onCommand
```

3.

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:14 char:17
+ foreach($row in $RequestBody.SearchResult.tables[0].rows)
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed the query language has changed. We have published a new sample here on how to parse results from the new language.

Look here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-alerts-actions#webhook-actions

Have a look at the new sample and see if you can use that to parse the records.

Thanks,
Anirudh

Comment: Please look at my jsonblob link - I try to parse results from new query language. I took it from Azure Portal (input data) but i differs from example from Your link. Does data passed to runbook realy is different from "input data" json?